# RegExpr в Delphi

Tags: регулярные-выражения, delphi

Доброе время суток. Хотелось бы поделиться с вами своей проблемой, и услышать ответ как её разрешить.
Всё в общем-то просто. Изначально я **считываю** текстовый файл формата **TUTDF** с помощью **Stream**, меняю кодировку для того чтобы Русские символы были видны, а дальше... дальше с помощью **регулярного выражения** я хочу каждую строку, **записать в элемент массива** чтобы продолжить работу уже над каждой строкой отдельно.

```
RegExp.InputString := ss;
  ss := RegExp.InputString;
   RegExp.Expression := '([A-Z]{1,3})'; // Было много вариантов (для теста)
    RegExp.ModifierG := true;

  if RegExp.Exec(Trim(ss)) then
  begin
    result1 := RegExp.Match[0]; 
    result2 := RegExp.Match[1];

    ShowMessage(result1 + ' ' + result2);
  end else
    showmessage('Не найдено');
```

И здесь начинается моя **проблема**. Совпадений, больше одного, вообще не находится, а иногда и вовсе **не ищется**. Где только не ходил, что не читал... а так и не понял... хотя если использовать онлайн инструменты для тестирование регулярного выражения, то всё работает замечательно. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема...

Comment: а что это за обмен такой:

    RegExp.InputString := ss;
    ss := RegExp.InputString;

> я хочу каждую строку, записать в элемент массива

для этого регулярки не нужны. С этим скорее всего справиться и TStringList.

Что это за формат такой "TUTDF" ?

Comment: TUTDF это формат "Кредитных историй" для банка. По поводу обмена... да, он странноватый но рабочий, а на счёт TStringList так мне кажется это нереально, ведь Stream.Read отдаёт мне 70000+ символов в 1 строку... т.е. её ещё нужно разбить.

Comment: Ещё я пробовал старым дедовским способом Readln сделать, и всё здорово, но скорость... просто убивает... поэтому решил попробовать Stream

Comment: у TStringList нет ограничения на длину строку (на самом деле оно есть, но это в районе 2 гигабайт).

Обмен работает (почему ему не работать, это просто ссылки). Но вторая строка обмена уже не нужна.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, вы можете дать мне конкретный ответ на вопрос, почему он не ищет все совпадения. Конкретней, меня интересует разделение строк по признаку #13#10 Т.е. всё что до этих символов, это должно быть элементом массива и так, пока не будет достигнут конец файла. На выходе должен быть массив из... например 300 элементов в каждом из которых строка. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: кто он? TStringList? может в файле разделители другие?

или код, который приведен выше? не, он не делит.

файл покажите.

Comment: Всё что мне нужно, это рабочее регулярное выражение которое в этой строке ищет #13#10 и ту часть которая была до него копирует в элемент массива, и так до конца файла.
Поставил в регулярное выражение   
RegExp.Expression := '\S{1,}';
Всегда показывает только 1 слово... дальше не двигается

Comment: Для этой задачи не нужно регулярное выражение. Обычный TStringList справиться на ура. Попробуйте.

> Всегда показывает только 1 слово... дальше не двигается

а он не обязан.

Comment: А как его использовать. Изначально, я считал данные с файла в Buffer: Utf8String; а для перекодировки текста Buffer я перевёл в ss:RawByteString; и в формат TStringList сейчас не идёт

Comment: @Сергей Кашурин дайте пример строки и как вы ее хотите разбить. и какой regexp (компонент) используете?  
Кстати stringlist разобьет вашу строку на несколько быстрее и реальнее чем манипуляции с регулярками.

Comment: если хочется гемороя то вот регулярка '/([^\r]+)/';
Иначе вариант без гемороя

    Var
      sList:TStringList;
    Begin
      sList:=TstringList.Create;
      sList.LoadFromFile({PatchToFile});//sList.LoadFromStream({Stream})
      //sList[i]<<ваш элемент массива с номером i 
      //sList.Count << кол-во записей(строк) в массиве.
    end.

Comment: Большое спасибо за пример. Но я достаточно мало знаю о Stream, можете ли дописать верх этого примера. У меня получилось так F:TextFile; далее Stream := TFileStream.Create('НАЗВАНИЕ ФАЙЛА', fmOpenRead); затем SetLength(buffer, Stream.Size);
    Stream.Read(Buffer[1], Stream.Size); и вся строка в 700000 символов получается тут Buffer а в вашем примере, когда я хочу встроить свой Stream он выдаёт ошибку

Comment: вот ваш текст, загруженный из файла и перекодировнный (из utf8):

  sl:=TStringList.Create;
  sl.LoadFromFile('c:\myfile.dat');
  sl.Text:=UTF8Decode(sl.text);

потоки вам использовать самостоятельно не нужно, stringlist сам за вас его использует в loadFromFile.  
вы лучше расскажите про TUTDF. это бинарный файл или текстовый (просто xml или как)? гугль рассказывает, что формат этот супер какой-то секретный. просто вполне возможно что вы делаете что-то не то и не так.

Comment: К сожалению ваш вариант не подошёл. Мне очень понравился вариант товарища ToRcH565. А на счёт формата... извините, не могу рассказать больше. Могу лишь указать направление. Это и правда весьма скрытный формат, и узнать о нём больше, вы сможете прочитав Положение 311-П

Comment: почитал. если правильно понял, кодировка там 866, а не utf. это не принципиально в данном случае. перекодировать похоже вы умеете и так (на всякий случай [вот функции](http://www.sysman.ru/index.php?showtopic=3719) перекодировки из 866 в ansi - подставить DosToWin вместо UTF8Decode и все)  
  
по поводу секретности формата, вы преувеличили. я естественно не просил вас выкладывать какую-либо конфиденциальную информацию. достаточно было бы примера. формат довольно простой. У TStringList'а есть свойство NameValueSeparator, установив которое в ':' можно получить и ключи значения для каждой строки

Comment: Что имеено здесь не так, и как правильно. Подскажите пожалуйста.
var
F:TextFile;
S, sf:string;
i:Integer;
sList:TStringList;

Buffer: Utf8String;
  Stream: TFileStream;
  MemoryStream : TMemoryStream;

  ss:RawByteString;

begin
Stream := TFileStream.Create('FILE_NAME', fmOpenRead);
  try

    SetLength(buffer, Stream.Size);
    Stream.Read(Buffer[1], Stream.Size);

    ss := Buffer;
    SetCodePage(ss, CP_ACP, False);
    Memo1.Lines.Text := ss;

  sList:=TstringList.Create;
  sList.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(sList.Count));

  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Большое Спасибо товарищам ToRcH565 и Yura Ivanov за помощь. Ваши варианты мне очень помогли и оказались простыми. С потоками ещё буду разбираться, и из TStringList пробовать парсить, но дело пошло куда быстрее с Вашими ответами. **Спасибо!**