# Как вставить запятые перед словами?

Tags: delphi

Как написать функцию, которая будет вставлять запятые перед "который", "которая", "которое", "которые", если они не являются первым словом предложения.

Comment: регистрозависимую замену слов сделайте да и все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kromster** дал слишком простой ответ (у вас могут появиться двойные запятые).

Видимо лучше всего такую замену сделать через RegExp.

Почитать можно тут:

- [Delphi XE. Работа с регулярными выражениями](http://www.webdelphi.ru/2010/09/delphi-xe-rabota-s-regulyarnymi-vyrazheniyami/)
- [RegExpr в Delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/256280/regexpr-%D0%B2-delphi)

Добавка:

Искать `'([^,]) (который|которая|которые) '` замена `'$1, $2 '` (обратите внимание на пробелы!).

```
uses
  ...
  System.RegularExpressions;

function DoReplace(const AText: string): string;
var  
  VPattern: string;
begin  
  VPattern := '([^,]) (который|которая|которые) ';
  Result := TRegEx.Replace(AText, VPattern, '$1, $2 ');
end;
```

Отладка регулярок удобна тут http://regexr.com/

Comment: Перенесите решение в ответ плиз, а ссылку давайте как дополнение. Спасибо за замечание, поправил свой ответ )

Comment: Ответ получился бы гораздо лучше, если бы вы написали регулярку и пример кода.

Comment: Добавил пример кода.

Comment: слово "некоторые" тоже сработает? :)

Comment: Обратите внимание, перед (и после) второй скобкой пробел, значит перед словом (и после) тоже должен быть пробел, иначе слово не будет найдено. Поэтому "некоторые" не будет найдено. И в конце предложения тоже не будет найдено. Если нужно, то такое поведение легко поменять, когда знаешь язык обращения к RegExp.

Comment: Похожий вопрос тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658210/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2

Answer (score 3):

Используйте замену текста стандартной функцией `StringReplace`. Вот так:

```
Result := StringReplace(aInput, ' который', ', который', [rfReplaceAll]);
Result := StringReplace(Result, ' которая', ', которая', [rfReplaceAll]);
Result := StringReplace(Result, ' которое', ', которое', [rfReplaceAll]);
Result := StringReplace(Result, ' которые', ', которые', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Флаг выставляем `rfReplaceAll` - "менять все вхождения".

Если опасаетесь двойных запятых, то можете добавить:

```
Result := StringReplace(Result, ',,', ',', [rfReplaceAll]);
```