# Регулярное выражение для выбора всех предлогов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, delphi, pcre

Мне в тексте нужно найти все предлоги. Для этого я использую следующее регулярное выражение: **(\s+?(?:это|как|так|и|в|над|к|до|не|на|но|за|то|с|ли|а|во|от|со|для|о|же|ну|вы|бы|что|кто|он|она)\s+?)**

в строке: *Разум дан человеку для того, чтобы он разумно жил, а не для того только, чтобы он понимал, что он неразумно живет*.

не выбирает в "*, а не для* " предлог "**не**" потому, что  "**а**" ограничен пробелами, "**не**" не выбирается так как его пробел забрала "**а**"

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59784/discussion-on-question-by-artem------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если необходимо найти данные слова между пробелами либо началом или концом строки, можно воспользоваться блоками просмотра назад `(?<!\S)` и вперёд `(?!\S)`:

```
(?<!\S)(?:это|как|так|и|в|над|к|до|не|на|но|за|то|с|ли|а|во|от|со|для|о|же|ну|вы|бы|что|кто|он|она)(?!\S)
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/tJYybB/5).

Если же любую букву можно найти с помщью `\p{L}`, то можно сформировать собственный шаблон границы слова:

```
(?<![_\d\p{L}])(?:это|как|так|и|в|над|к|до|не|на|но|за|то|с|ли|а|во|от|со|для|о|же|ну|вы|бы|что|кто|он|она)(?![_\d\p{L}])
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/v8BwuT/1).

Здесь `(?<![_\d\p{L}])` задаёт  начальную границу слова: если перед ним окажется `_`, цифра или буква, поиск текущего совпадения прекратится, движок займётся поиском следующего. Блок предварительного просмотра вперёд  `(?![_\d\p{L}])` работает точно так же, но только проверяет символы после необходимого слова.